# CSS jQuery selector nth child

Tags: jquery, css

```
    <table>
     <tr>
          <td>1</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>3</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>4</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>5</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>6</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>7</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>8</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

i want to color 4th and 5th and 6th with different color
how do I select it thru nth child. having difficulties understanding it

```
table tr:first-child{background-color: #F57676;}
table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #F5B3B3;}
table tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #F2DCDC;}
table tr:last-child{ background-color: #F57676;}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything from your side yet?

Comment: Here it is http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: refer http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/erupenkman/ytq83/)

Use the [nth-child(n+x)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) syntax to specify an offset, this selects the fourth row and above

```
tr:nth-child(n+4) {
  background-color: #FAA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use. Here we select the 4th and 5th tr child of the table.

```
table tr:nth-child(4),
table tr:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("table").find("tr:eq(3),tr:eq(4)").addClass("cls");
```

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/4658m/)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule I tend not to use Nth child as it's backwards compatibility is rather limited. I recommend applying html/css class names like 'class="4th"' instead as it will work on more legacy browsers.

If you plan on implementing it in jquery any way, use this reference 
[site](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: this is true but becoming less relevant, supports ie9+ and all other major browsers

Comment: Agreed, however on larger scale sites, places like china and middle eastern countries still have high percentages of things like ie6. In general i tend to aim for IE9 upwards but it's just something to bare in mind.